# Dereferencing a pointer at lower level in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

When malloc returns a pointer (a virtual address of a block of data),

```
char *p = malloc (10);
```

p has a virtual address, (say x). And `p` holds a virtual address of a block of 10 addresses.
Say these virtual addresses are from y to y+10.

These 10 addresses belong to a page , and the virtual --> physical mapping is  placed in the page table.

When processor dereferences the pointer p, say `printf("%c", *p);` , how does the processor know that it has to access the address at `y` ?

**Is the page table accessed twice in order to dereference a pointer ,in other words -print the address pointed by `p` ? How exactly is it done, can anybody explain ?**

Also, for accessing stack variables, does the processor have to access it through page table ?
Isn't the stack pointer register (SP) not pointing to the stack already ?

Comment: You understand that malloc is not defined as returning a "virtual address" (i.e. it is implementation-specific) ?.

Comment: Suppose we assume in this case that it returns virtual address ?

However, I'm aware that it returns a pointer (an address of a block of memory in the heap).

The returned address could be physical/virtual. Anyways, now my question is whether the processor has to visit the page-table for the second time in order to access the data in the heap, if the returned address is virtual.

Comment: Typo: The 10 objects are located `y` to `y+9`. A pointer is allowed to point to `y+10` (i.e. the location *after* the ten objects) but you are not allowed to dereference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a muddling of different layers.

First, ***page tables***: This is a data structure that uses some memory to provide pointers to more memory.  Given a particular virtual address, it can deconstruct it into indices into the table.  Right now, this is happening under the cover in the kernel, but it's possible to implement this same idea in user space.

Now, the next step is ***processes***.  Each process gets its own view of memory and hence has its one set of page tables.  How the processor know where these different page tables reside?  In a special control register called **cr3**.  Changing processes is sometimes called a context switch; and rightly so because setting cr3 changes the processes view of virtual memory.

But the next question is, how does the processor even understand the concept of virtual memory?  Well, in some older architectures (MIPs comes to mind), the system would keep a cache of recently translated memory and provides guidance for how to handle virtual memory access.  In x86, the cache (more commonly called a **translation lookaside buffer**) is actually implemented in hardware.  The processor stores these translations so it can handle the page table lookups automatically.  If there's a cache miss, then it will actually traverse the page table structure as set up by the OS to lookup what it should reference.

Of course, this means there must be at least two different modes for the processor: one that assumes the addresses are direct and one that traverses the page tables.  The first mode, **real mode**, is there on boot and only around long enough to set up the tables before the bootloader turns on **virtual mode** and jumps to the beginning of the rest of the code.

---

The short answer to my long explanation is that in all likelihood, the page tables aren't accessed at all because the processor already has the address translations.

Answer (score -1):

> And p holds a virtual address of a block of 10 addresses.

You're confused.  `p` is a pointer holding the address of a 10-byte block; how these bytes are interpreted is up to the application.

Comment: Pedantically speaking, the poster is correct, that there are 10 addresses.  (It's not guaranteed that there aren't more than 10 addresses in the block, but the C standard guarantees that there are at *least* 10 addresses, and I know of no platform where there aren't exactly 10.)

Comment: I interpreted his sentence and example as `p[0]==y`, `p[1]==y+1` where `y` is some pointer value.